# Why mysql query is taking too much time to fetch results?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that contains two tables one is `users` and `users_activity`.

Users Activity table have some columns including `userid` that match's with user table's id.

I want to get some result from both tables using JOINS.

Here's my MySQL query. Please let me know what's my mistake / Why this query is taking too much time?

```
SELECT ua.userid, COUNT(ua.id) user_active, u.name 
FROM `user_activity` ua, users u 
WHERE   ua.target = 'Save Post' OR 
        ua.target = 'Send comment' OR 
        ua.target = 'Send Reply' 
        AND ua.created_on >= 1630454401 
        AND ua.userid = u.id 
GROUP BY ua.userid 
ORDER BY COUNT(ua.userid) DESC LIMIT 5
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Put brackets around bits of your where clause if you are using AND and OR together otherwise the DB will do a lot more than you actually intended it to do, depending on what order you place things

```
SELECT ua.userid, COUNT(ua.id) user_active, u.name 
    FROM `user_activity` ua, users u 
    WHERE 
        (
        ua.target = 'Save Post' OR 
        ua.target = 'Send comment' OR 
        ua.target = 'Send Reply' 
        )
    AND ua.created_on >= 1630454401 
    GROUP BY ua.userid 
    ORDER BY COUNT(ua.userid) DESC 
    LIMIT 5
```

Of course if you are processing a billion rows some time will be involved

Also you should get used to the JOIN syntax rather than the old comma seperated list of tables. They are much more flexible and efficient

```
SELECT ua.userid, COUNT(ua.id) user_active, u.name 
FROM user_activity ua 
    JOIN users u ON ua.userid = u.id
WHERE 
    (
    ua.target = 'Save Post' OR 
    ua.target = 'Send comment' OR 
    ua.target = 'Send Reply' 
    )
AND ua.created_on >= 1630454401 
AND ua.userid = u.id 
GROUP BY ua.userid 
ORDER BY COUNT(ua.userid) DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Never heared of the advantage of using brackets on `OR`, do you think it also aplies to `AND` ?

Comment: HI @B001ᛦ No, when using BOTH and AND or in the same query. Did i explain badly?

Comment: Hi :) I'm a fan of your explanations across SO, I meant a query using only ANDs e.g. `WHERE(a=1 AND b=2 AND c=3)`

Comment: @B001ᛦ No I know of no benefit in that senario and I am not a fan of unnecessary brackets in a query or anywhere else come to that

Comment: The brackets are purely to tell MySQL that the OR applies only to those 3 conditions. Mixing AND's and OR's together can confuse that as well as us meer mortals :) @B001ᛦ

Comment: You can use more compact and clear form `... WHERE ua.target IN ('Save Post', 'Send comment', 'Send Reply') AND ...`

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev thats right you can, but that would not have helped the OP understand why they were getting this issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly, sure, it just comment, not answer. By the way `.. FROM user_activity ua JOIN users u ON ua.userid = u.id ...`  better then `... FROM user_activity ua, users u  ... WHERE ... ua.userid = u.id  ...`

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Now that is a very valid comment, I will amend my answer, didnt spot that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT ua.userid, COUNT(ua.id)  As user_active, u.name 
    FROM `user_activity` ua INNER JOIN users u 
     ON ua.userid = u.id  
    AND  ua.target IN ( 'Save Post' ,'Send comment','Send Reply') 
            AND ua.created_on >= 1630454401 
           GROUP BY ua.userid  ORDER BY COUNT(ua.userid) DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Welcome If It Works Vote Up and Mark it  As Answer Accepted so it can also be beneficial for community.